# Copying array to map results in same items in map

Tags: go

I am doing this kind of array copy to map

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Test struct {
    Id int
    Name string
}

func main() {
    tlist := []Test{
        Test{1, "mike"},
        Test{2, "clara"},
        Test{3, "stefan"},
    }
    
    tmap := make(map[int]*Test)

   // copy to map here
    for _, t := range tlist {
        tmap[t.Id] = &t
        fmt.Printf("list to map %v\n", tmap[t.Id])
    }
    
   // debug
    for _, t := range tmap {
        t.Name = t.Name + "A"
        fmt.Printf("%v\n", t)
    }
    
    for _, t := range tlist {
        fmt.Printf("list after %v\n", t)
    }
}
```

The resulting output is that the map contains only last array item in all map items.

```
list to map &{1 mike}
list to map &{2 clara}
list to map &{3 stefan}
&{3 stefanA}
&{3 stefanAA}
&{3 stefanAAA}
list after {1 mike}
list after {2 clara}
list after {3 stefan}
```

Why does the map only contains the last array's item when printing the map after printing each map element correctly on the first loop ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you took address of *t* variable in your first loop. So all 3 values in map are pointers to the *t* variable and *t* variable stores last element of *tlist* after loop completes. You should save pointers not to loop variable *t* but to slice elements directly:

```
for i, t := range tlist {
    tmap[t.Id] = &tlist[i]
    fmt.Printf("list to map %v\n", tmap[t.Id])
}
```